# Construct graph connectivity matrices in COO format

Tags: python, numpy, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have faced the following subtask while working with graph data:

I need to **construct graph connectivity matrices in COO format** for graphs with several fully-connected components from arrays of "border" indices.

As an example, given array

```
borders = [0, 2, 5]
```

the resulting COO matrix should be

```
coo_matrix = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]].
```

That is, **borders** array contains **ranges** of nodes that should form fully-connected subgraphs (starting index included and ending index excluded).

I came up with the following algorithm, but I suspect that the perfomance could be improved:

```
import numpy as np

def get_coo(borders):

    edge_list = []
    for s, e in zip(borders, borders[1:]):
        
        # create fully-connected subgraph
        arr = np.arange(s, e)
        t = np.array(np.meshgrid(arr, arr)).T.reshape(-1, 2)
        t = t.T

        edge_list.append(t)

    edge_list = np.concatenate(edge_list, axis=1)

    return edge_list
```

I feel there may be a **faster solution**, maybe using some numpy vectorized operations.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do check the different solutions I show in my answer. Depending on how you want to utilize this further, it might be a good idea to use `networkx` or `itertools`

Comment: Were you able to check the approaches I showcase below? Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Yes, thanks for the answer! It speeds up code indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your goal is a faster solution than what you have, you can explore `itertools` for solving this efficiently. This approach benchmarks **approximately 25 times** faster than your current approach as tested on larger `border` lists.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, chain

def get_coo(borders):
    edges = chain(*[product(range(*i),repeat=2) for i in zip(borders, borders[1:])])
    return list(edges)

output = get_coo(borders)

## NOTE: Remember to can convert to array and Transpose for all approaches below to get Coo format.
np.array(output).T
```

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]])
```

---

## Alternate approaches and benchmarks:

> Note: These have been benchmarked on your current small list as well as on a larger border list as generated by `borders = np.arange(300)[np.random.randint(0,2,(300,),dtype=bool)]`

#### Disjoint union of complete graphs

What you are trying to do is essentially combine disjoint complete graphs. Adjacency matrices for such graphs have complete connections for selective items along it's diagonal. You can use `networkx` to solve these.

[image]

While slower than your current solution, you will find that working on these graphs objects would be much much easier and rewarding than using NumPy to represent graphs.

**Approach 1:**

1. Assuming that nodes are in sequence, calculate the number of nodes in each subgraph as `i`
2. Create a complete matrix filled with 1s of the shape `i*i`
3. Combine the graphs using `nx.disjoint_union_all`
4. Fetch the edges of this graph

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

def get_coo(borders):
    graphs = [nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.ones((i,i))).to_directed() for i in np.diff(borders)]
    edges = nx.disjoint_union_all(graphs).edges()
    return edges

%timeit get_coo(borders)

#Small- 277 µs ± 33.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#Large- 300 ms ± 36.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Approach 2:**

1. Iterate over the rolling 2-gram tuples of the `borders` using `zip`
2. Create `nx.complete_graph` using `ranges(start, end)` from these tuples
3. Combine the graphs using `nx.disjoint_union_all`
4. Fetch the edges of this graph

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

def get_coo(borders):
    graphs = [nx.complete_graph(range(*i),nx.DiGraph()) for i in zip(borders, borders[1:])]
    edges = nx.disjoint_union_all(graphs).edges()
    return edges

%timeit get_coo(borders)

#Small- 116 µs ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
#Large- 207 ms ± 35.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*Output is a bit faster than previous but lacks the self-loops on the nodes which would have to be added separately*

#### Using `itertools.product`

**Approach 3:**

1. Iterate over the rolling 2-gram tuples of the `borders` using `zip`
2. Use `itertools.product` completely connected edge list for each subgraph
3. Use `itertools.chain` to "append" the two iterators
4. Return them as edges

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, chain

def get_coo(borders):
    edges = chain(*[product(range(*i),repeat=2) for i in zip(borders, borders[1:])])
    return list(edges)

%timeit get_coo(borders)

#Small- 3.91 µs ± 787 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
#Large- 183 µs ± 21.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

*This approach is approximately 25 times faster than your current approach*

#### Your current approach - benchmark

```
def get_coo(borders):

    edge_list = []
    for s, e in zip(borders, borders[1:]):
        
        # create fully-connected subgraph
        arr = np.arange(s, e)
        t = np.array(np.meshgrid(arr, arr)).T.reshape(-1, 2)
        t = t.T

        edge_list.append(t)

    edge_list = np.concatenate(edge_list, axis=1)

    return edge_list

%timeit get_coo(borders)

#Small- 95.1 µs ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
#Large- 3.91 ms ± 962 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```